# d3j : Remove a data set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to remove a curve when a checkbox is unchecked. I tried this without success:

```
function drawdata(fileno,draw){
    var name="circle"+fileno;
    if (draw) {
        console.log("Drawing file "+fileno+ " ("+files[fileno]+")");
        svg.selectAll(name) .data(datasets[fileno]) .enter() .append("circle")
        .attr('cx',function(a){ return xscales[xval](a[xval]); })
        .attr('cy',function(a){ return yscales[yval](a[yval]); })
        .attr('r',3)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        ;
    } else {
        console.log("removing file "+fileno);
        svg.selectAll(name).data(datasets[fileno]).exit().remove();
    }
}
```

The first part work well (ie if I check a checkbox the file is plotted) but when I uncheck it, it is not removed from the svg. I guess I do not understand the exit well. Can someone point out what is wrong? Thanks.

Sample jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/datavis/530h1qLw/11/#&togetherjs=Rkz5QyDgJm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

With the addition of the fiddle, it's pretty easy to see what is going on.  When you do `svg.selectAll(name)` it's returning an empty selection.  The reason for that is because there are no elements of `circleN`.  `circleN` is not a valid DOM element, and none of them exist anyway, so the selection will fail.

If you make the following changes to your `cds` function you will see that your code now works:

```
function cds(el) {
    name = "circle" + el.id;
    if (el.checked) {
        svg.selectAll(name)
            .data(dataset[el.id])
          .enter().append("circle")
            .attr('cx', function (a) { return xscale(a[0]); })
            .attr('cy', function (a) { return yscale(a[1]); })
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('class', name)        
            .style("opacity", 1);
    } else {
        svg.selectAll("circle." + name).remove();
    }
}
```

There are two changes of note in this function:

1. `.attr('class', name)` being added to the code creating your new DOM elements.  This will add a class to the circle, making the selection easier when it comes time to remove them.
2. Updated the line that removes them to `svg.selectAll("circle." + name).remove();` which will remove the circles when you uncheck the radio boxes.

Comment: `svg.selectAll(name).remove()` was the first thing I tried, and that did not work.